# How can I find the rotation of a document?

Tags: computer-vision, ocr

Take the following scanned image as an example:

[image]

By looking at the borders, you can clearly see that it is rotated slightly to the left. How can I detect the amount of this rotation? (In order to fix it)

Edge detection would "highlight" the border, but except for trying many rotations and building an x- / y- histogram I don't know how to use this information. And the iterative approach seems to be more computationally intensive than appropriate for such a simple problem.

I am looking for Pseudo-code / an algorithmic idea. Hence I didn't tag this question with a programming language. However, if you like to give code, I prefer Python.

Answer (score 3):

What about the following approach (assuming the amount of rotation is small and there are indeed enough horizontal / vertical line features in the document):

1. Extract all (parametric) lines in the document via a [Hough transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform),
2. Classify lines as either close to horizontal or vertical (and simply discard the ones that can't be classified up to some tolerance),
3. Robustly fit a rotation to minimize the deviation of the lines from their expected orientation ([RANSAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_sample_consensus) variant with a rotation solver).

For 3., one could start without any RANSAC (just fit a best rotation to all the horizontal / vertical lines) and only add it if there are noticeable blunders that need to be taken care of.

Regarding fitting a rotation to lines, each line can be parameterized with a unit 2D vector `n` and a scalar `d` s.t. a 2D point `M` belongs to the line iff `n . M + d = 0`. The vector `n` gives the orientation of the line and based on the classification is expected to be close to a reference vector `n_0` (`e_x`, `-e_x`, `e_y` or `-e_y` depending on the actual classification). So a possible objective function would be `F(theta) = argmax_theta 1/2 sum_i | ( R(theta) n^i ) . n_0^i |^2` where `theta` is the angle of the 2D rotation to apply, `R(theta)` the corresponding 2 x 2 rotation matrix. This objective function finds the rotation that maximizes the alignment between the rotated line vectors and the expected line vectors. If the square is dropped from the objective function, then the objective function actually boils down to a simplified [Kabsch algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kabsch_algorithm) / absolute orientation in 2D without translation / scale which can be solved with an SVD.

Answer (score 0):

The [deskew package](https://pypi.org/project/deskew/) works pretty well for normal text documents. It doesn't work well for images and also not for the given example.